# How to map json to object using spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Hello I'd like to know how I could mapp my json message to object in java when using spring boot.

Let's say I'm getting json like

```
 {
    "customerId": 2,
    "firstName": "Jan",
    "lastName": "Nowak",
    "town": "Katowice"
  }
```

and I'd like to make it entity in my java program:
**and for whatever reason I dont want to have match on field names**

```
public class Customer {


    //Something like @Map("customerId")
    private long OMG;
    //Something like @Map("firstName")
    private String WTF;
    //Something like @Map("lastName")
    private String LOL;
    //Something like @Map("town")
    private String YOLO;
```

I cannot find what annotation I should use, Not using jackson, just built in spring boot converter??

Comment: Spring Boot does grouping dependencies,  glue and default configuration. It is not a serialization api. You should use Jackson to perform your need

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring boot comes with Jackson out-of-the-box.

You can use @RequestBody Spring MVC annotation to un-marshall json string to Java object... something like this.

> ```
> @RestController
> public class CustomerController {
>     //@Autowired CustomerService customerService;
>
>     @RequestMapping(path="/customers", method= RequestMethod.POST)
>     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
>     public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
>         //return customerService.createCustomer(customer);
>     }
> }
> ```

Annotate your entities member elements with @JsonProperty with corresponding json field names.

> ```
> public class Customer {
>     @JsonProperty("customerId")
>     private long OMG;
>     @JsonProperty("firstName")
>     private String WTF;
>     @JsonProperty("lastName")
>     private String LOL;
>     @JsonProperty("town")
>     private String YOLO;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot does grouping dependencies, glue and default configuration. It is not a serialization api. You should use Jackson to perform your need

You shoud map your class such as :

```
public class Customer {

  @JsonProperty("customerId")
  private long OMG;
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  private String WTF;
  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String LOL;
  @JsonProperty("town")
  private String YOLO;  
   ....
}
```

From JsonProperty annotation Javadoc :

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a
>   "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its
>   signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized,
>   deserialized) as a logical property.
>
> Default value ("") indicates that the field name is used as the
>   property name without any modifications, but it can be specified to
>   non-empty value to specify different name. Property name refers to
>   name used externally, as the field name in JSON objects.