# HttpServletRequest in spring getting parameters values as null for post request

Tags: spring, post, request-mapping

```
@ResponseBody

@RequestMapping(value = {"apiRequest"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})

public String contestApiSignUp(HttpServletRequest req) throws JSONException {
try {
    String username = req.getParameter("username");
    String firstname = req.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = req.getParameter("lastname");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String phone = req.getParameter("phone");
```

Here the values I am getting all are null. That is username =null, firstname =null...

I am hitting post request with the values 
http://localhost:8080/apiRequest.htm

```
username = Subhajit
firstname = Subha
...
```

like this.

But while I am using same code but,

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"apiRequest"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
```

using GET instead of POST then I am getting the proper values.

Comment: can you show your exact post request with headers

Answer (score 0):

When you sent your HTML Form by POST to your URL /apiRequest, did you fill your data (username, firstname etc.) in fields in your form, or did you attached them to the sent URL (eg. `apiRequest.htm?username=test&...`) ?

Because with the second approach, you data will be accessible only through a GET request, not a POST. The first approach will work with a POST request.

Also, you do not need to call explicitly getParameter on the HttpServletRequest in a Spring Controller.

You can do this :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping (value = "apiRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String contestApiSignUp(
        @RequestParam ("username") String username,
        @RequestParam ("firstname") String firstname,
        @RequestParam ("lastname") String lastname,
        @RequestParam ("password") String password,
        @RequestParam ("phone") String phone) {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply. " apiRequest.htm?username=test& " I am not posting the data like this. I am using postman setting the params as headers and its values.

Comment: Ok, I never used postman, but it should work like other API request tools. You should not try to pass arbitrary key/value pairs in the headers of your request. These headers are for the metadata of the request, not the data. To pass data in a POST request, you must build a request body containing theses key/value pairs. Check the doc of postman, you can do so with a form-like interface. See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests, section Request Body > form-data.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you said you are trying with postman to post the request, So are you building website or webservices? **either way you should not be sending your data in the headers.**

- If you are building a website put together an HTML file from which
  you can submit a form to this controller
- If you are building webservice, change the controller and let it
  accept JSON (or XML -I would discourage this though) body. Follow
  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226580/6785908. And then from
  postman (or curl), post a json instead.