# How to turn a String into ArrayList<Details>?

Tags: java, spring-boot

The browser sends the following object to the backend:

[image]

Now I would like to store the data in my database. So I have an entity that looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class NewQuote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Details.class)
    private List<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();

    public NewQuote(String description, ArrayList<Details> details) {
        this.description = description;
        this.details = details;
    }
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class Details {
    private String description;
    private String label;

    public Details(String description, String label) {
        this.description = description;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public Details() {}
}
```

**Controller**

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/save-quote", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void saveQuote(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data) {
    newQuoteService.saveQuote(data);
}
```

**Service**

```java
public void saveQuote(Map<String, String> data) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    NewQuote newQuote = new NewQuote(
            json.getAsString("description"),
            json.getAsString("details")
    );
    newQuoteRepository.save(newQuote);
}
```

I am getting an error because `json.getAsString("details")` should not be a string of course. So how can I turn it to `ArrayList<Details>`?

Comment: Create a POJO that reflects your request payload instead of Map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map json to object using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226481/how-to-map-json-to-object-using-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `DTO` to manage your `json` response. You don't need to explicitly use `JSONObject` because `spring` already manage the process of mapping under the wood with `Jackson`.
Also, it is not a good practice to pass your Entities directly into the controller methods.

NewQuoteDto.java

```
public class NewQuoteDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private List<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();

    public NewQuoteDto() {
       
    }

    // getter and setter or you can use lombok
}
```

DetailDto.java

```
public class DetailDto {
    private String description;
    private String label;

    public DetailDto() {}

    // getter and setter or you can use lombok
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save-quote", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void saveQuote(@RequestBody NewQuoteDto dataDto) {
    // here you map dataDto to your model before you call saveQuote
    NewQuote data = mapper.map(dataDto, NewQuote.class); // if you use ModelMapper library.
    newQuoteService.saveQuote(data);
}
```

For custom mapping take look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper).